# Azure AD keeps sync a full deleted AD-User

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory

We created a test-user in AD and he got sync.
After all the tests we have done, we didnt need him anymore.
I deleted the User from AD and from the "Deleted-Users" (AD-hard deleted).
I cannot find him neither in AD nor with Powershell.
I deleted them even on Azure AD Dashboard (hard delete) and with Powershell (remove-msoluser), but after the Sync they keep getting back.
How can be possible, to keep synching an user, wo doenst exist anymore?
Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks in Advice. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try permanently delete a user from your organization without waiting the 30 days for automatic deletion. A permanently deleted user can't be restored by you.

Go to ***azure portal** -> **Users** ->select **Deleted users**  -> **Delete permanently***.

[image]

Otherwise, try to ***Remove a user from the Recycle Bin*** as below cmdlet, It permanently removes a deleted user from the recycle Bin. Even after you sync.

```
  Remove-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName  user@Contoso.com -RemoveFromRecycleBin
```

If its still licensed, you can remove all the licenses before proceeding.

```
Remove-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName  user@Contoso.com -Force
```

For more information in detail, please **refer** below links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/remove-msoluser?view=azureadps-1.0#example-3--remove-a-user-from-the-recycle-bin

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your response. I've already done everything u said (a couple of times) but the User keeps showing up after the sync.

Comment: where you're getting back user, in azure AD or AD , or in both ?

Comment: only in azure AD (+Office365 Dashboard). In AD those users are completly deleted.

Comment: I could solve it. I just had to connect the Azure AD Connect again with the same configuration and refreshed everything - the benutzer were finally gone.
Thanks for ur time.